# "Famille sommable" in English

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

In French, given a normed vector space $(E, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$, we say that a set of vectors $\mathcal C = \{c_i \ ; \ i \in I\}$ is a "[famille sommable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famille_sommable)" when
$$(\forall \epsilon > 0) \, (\exists J_0 \in \mathcal F(I)) \, (\forall K \in \mathcal F(I \setminus J_0)) \, \left\Vert \displaystyle \sum_{k \in K} c_k \right\Vert< \epsilon$$

where $\mathcal F(A)$ is defined as the sets of finite subsets of $A$.

**Is there a similar wording in English?** At least Wikipedia page I provided above is not refering to a similar an English page.

*Note: this question has for root cause [Uncountable sum of vectors in a Hilbert Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061489/uncountable-sum-of-vectors-in-a-hilbert-space).*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Summations_over_arbitrary_index_sets ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a “summable family”. That's the expression that is used in the English version of Bourbaki's *General Topology*.